# Ubuntu 16.04 software update never ends

Tags: update-manager

Newbie using Ubuntu 16.04 on Sony VAIO laptop

Opened Ubuntu Software and noticed that 11 programs needed updating.
Clicked on The Update (11) button at the top and it displayed the 11 programs.
Clicked on the Update button in the top of that window and all the program buttons changed to show being updated.
Later, the Update display changed to the "busy" signal, that circle going around endlessly.

And it has been that way for two days now.

Did I do something wrong?

How do I stop it? And then what is the correct procedure to do updates? One at a time?

WillB

Comment: Which programs are you trying to update? Just to let you know, the software center is very buggy under 16.04 (at least on my device). It won't refresh, won't properly remove programs, and will get stuck on an update loop.

Comment: Just reboot (or log off) an do the updates in terminal with just two commands in one:  *sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade*.

Comment: I apologize for my late response but we had a water leak in the condo which required replaceing all our floors with insurance discussions, move-out then back in, and more. But thank you again.